# PageView and AnimateToPage - How to dynamically animate to Page to the scrolled position in Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-pageview

I have cards which are getting scrolled successfully through a Page Controller and animate to Page. Now my issue is that even though it is iterated correctly, if I scroll myself to the right or left it leaves me back at the starting position aka _currentPage=0. I want the system to know dynamically that if 0 is the starting position and I have scrolled manually to the 3rd position, I want it to go to the 4th position and not start at the 0th position again. Similarly, if I have scrolled backwards to the 6th position I want it to go forward from where I scrolled not back to 0.  Is there a way to achieve this dynamically?

Please refer to the Timer.periodic code I tried adding a gesture Detector but that wouldn't work the program would not scroll at all.

```
 Timer _mytimer;
  bool _mytimerz = false;
  int _timerspeed = 15;
  int _currentPage = 0;
  bool _speedtime = false;
  PageController _pageController = PageController(
    initialPage: 0,
  );

  // timerforthisThis() {

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tests = [
      widget.label00,
      widget.label0,
      widget.label1,
      widget.label2,
      widget.label3,
      widget.label4,
      widget.label5,
      widget.label6,
      widget.label7,
      widget.label8,
      widget.label9,
      widget.label10,
      widget.label11,
      widget.label12,
      widget.label13,
      widget.label14,
      widget.label15,
      widget.label16,
      widget.label17,
      widget.label18,
      widget.label19,
      widget.label20,
      widget.label21,
      widget.label22,
      widget.label23,
      widget.label24,
      widget.label25,
      widget.label26,
      widget.label27,
      widget.label28,
      widget.label29,
      widget.label30,
      widget.label31,
      widget.label32,
      widget.label33,
      widget.label34,
      widget.label35,
      widget.label36,
      widget.label37,
    ];

    results = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
      if (widget.label00 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label00);
      }
      if (widget.label0 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label0);
      }
      if (widget.label1 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label1);
      }
      if (widget.label2 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label2);
      }
      if (widget.label3 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label3);
      }
      if (widget.label4 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label4);
      }
      if (widget.label5 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label5);
      }
      if (widget.label6 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label6);
      }
      if (widget.label7 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label7);
      }
      if (widget.label8 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label8);
      }
      if (widget.label9 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label9);
      }
      if (widget.label10 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label10);
      }
      if (widget.label11 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label11);
      }
      if (widget.label12 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label12);
      }
      if (widget.label13 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label13);
      }
      if (widget.label14 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label14);
      }
      if (widget.label15 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label15);
      }
      if (widget.label16 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label16);
      }
      if (widget.label17 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label17);
      }
      if (widget.label18 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label18);
      }
      if (widget.label19 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label19);
      }
      if (widget.label20 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label20);
      }
      if (widget.label21 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label21);
      }
      if (widget.label22 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label22);
      }
      if (widget.label23 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label23);
      }
      if (widget.label24 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label24);
      }
      if (widget.label25 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label25);
      }

      if (widget.label26 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label26);
      }
      if (widget.label27 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label27);
      }
      if (widget.label28 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label28);
      }
      if (widget.label29 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label29);
      }
      if (widget.label30 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label30);
      }
      if (widget.label31 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label31);
      }
      if (widget.label32 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label32);
      }
      if (widget.label33 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label33);
      }
      if (widget.label34 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label34);
      }
      if (widget.label35 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label35);
      }
      if (widget.label36 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label36);
      }
      if (widget.label37 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label37);
      }
    }

    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer timer) {
      // if (_mytimerz = true) {
      //   timer.cancel();
      // }

      // if (_speedtime = false) {
      //   Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) {});

      if (_currentPage < results.length) {
        _currentPage++;
        // _currentPage++;
      }
      // _speedtime = true;
      // timer.cancel();

      // } else {
      // GestureDetector(onPanUpdate: (details) {
      //   if (details.delta.dx > 0 || details.delta.dx < 0) {
      //     print("right");
      //   }
      // });
      //   _currentPage = _currentPage;
      //   // 0
      // }

      _pageController
          .
          // animateTo(
          // _pageController.,

          // duration: , curve: curve)
          animateToPage(
        // results.length,
        _currentPage = _currentPage,
        duration:
            //  _speedtime
            // ?
            // Duration(milliseconds: 0),
            // :
            Duration(milliseconds: 350),
        curve: Curves.easeIn,
      );
    }
        // );

        // );
        // }
        );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

- First, have a variable to feed the page view index like `pageViewIndex`
- Initialise the `PageController` in the `initState` method with the `pageViewIndex`
- Then in the `PageView`'s `onPageChanged` method do `setState` for the `pageViewIndex` and animate the PageController to the (new) `pageViewIndex`

Hope that should do.
Comment down if any other help is needed.